# CSS Selector <tag name>#<ID> Patterns -- Any Siginifance?

Tags: css

When working on a web project with a 'not so good' codebase, I often see in JS/CSS selectors written like

```
div#myID
```

This seems wrong....

http://jsfiddle.net/bobber205/yeJRQ/

Example above. This means, if for some reason, you change the tag the id belongs to, you have, possible, LOTS of css to change....

What's up with people doing that? Is it faster? Is the speed improvement worth it? So curious. :P

Answer (score 5):

That's a *really* bad practice. ID selectors are unique by definition. Including tag or class qualifiers just adds redundant information that needs to be evaluated needlessly. So it's no speed improvement at all - it's a useless slow down.

Answer (score 4):

There could be a use case for that.
For example if you have `span#myID` for inline element or `div#myID` for block element (in different pages of course) and want to apply different styles.

But as @Zoltan Toth noticed it is usually a case of "will put tag name in just in case" behaviour of people who aren't familiar enough with CSS selectors basics.

In 99% of cases if you are selecting something with ID you should just use ID. It's unique.

Comment: That being said, each ID should be unique, regardless of the tag that it is in. If these elements are mutually exclusive, I *could* see you getting away with styling them separately, but even so, I would recommend using two different (unique) IDs.

Comment: Having two elements with the same `id` can cause problems (I think in IE). Use classes for that. That's what they are designed for, like `span#myClass` and `div#myClass` can have different styles.

Comment: yes IDs should be unique, always, that's why I said "(in different pages of course)". And @Wex, your comment makes a lot of sense - I suppose if you can change the markup from div to span, then you should be able to change the ID too.